# Access control system for a club

Tags: home-security, rfid

A UK-based friend has asked my to recommend a single access control system for a members club/bar* with a single door. (* despite the "home-security" tag).

[Update] he now tells me that it should control two doors.

There is an existing system with RFID card based entry, but the suppliers are now asking for GBP 20 for each new card. (I will ask them to try a few different cards which I supply; unless there is a range of acceptable numbers, that should work).

Budget: as cheap as possible, max "a few hundred GBP".

Must have:

- card based entry
- easily installed
- easily administered by non-tech people (we can assume average Windows/Android knowledge)
- uses cheap, easily obtainable RFID cards

Nice to have:

- fingerprint based entry
- possibly face recognition? If so, optional on a per-member basis, as should be fingerprinting

As I understand it, the current system requires a PC (windows 95 based is currently being used :-), but I see no reason that the new one should have to, unless this makes it easier for the users (club secretary/committee members). It might also add expense if a Widows 10 PC must be purchased (and I don't know what legacy software they might be running on that Windows 95 PC).

Only entry is required, no time-keeping, or even record keeping, but such an over-spec'ed system is acceptable if extra features don't get in the way of "the door should open to members and to no one else".

I suppose that they would have to fit a new lock to the door?

I can look around AliExpress, but would prefer a recommendation, preferably from someone with experience of this sort of thing.

Comment: Does your friend's insurance policy place any restrictions on what entry mechanisms he can use? They might decide that the place wasn't sufficiently secured in case of a burglary. And cheap RFID cards will be trivially easy to clone.